# MS-Access: Delete duplicate rows but keep the one with the latest date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and MS-Access and could need some help. My table looks like this and I want to delete all rows, where `C1`, `C2` and `C3` are the same but keep the row with the latest date. In this case I would like to delete the rows with `ID` 2 and 5.

```
ID  |  C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  Date   |
1   |  a   |  a   |  b   | 01.04.20|
2   |  a   |  a   |  b   | 01.03.19|
3   |  a   |  b   |  b   | 01.04.20|
4   |  a   |  b   |  c   | 01.04.20|
5   |  a   |  b   |  c   | 07.05.19|
```

I tried to numerate the rows using `ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY C1,C2,C3 ORDER BY Date ASC)` so I could delete all rows with a Rownumber >1. But unfortunately `PARTITION BY` doesn't work in Access.

Do you have another idea how I could manage that?

The following query gives me the Table I want. But how can I go on with this?

```sql
SELECT C1,C2,C3, max(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY C1,C2,C3
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t as t2
                where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c2 and t2.c3 = t.c3
               );
```

You can delete the rows with similar logic:

```
delete from t
where t.date < (select max(t2.date)
                from t as t2
                where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c2 and t2.c3 = t.c3
               );
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will try that, but won't the second query delete all rows with the max date? I want to keep the row with the max date and delete all the other rows. So would it work with "where t.date <> (select max(t2.date)......)" ?

Comment: It would but I would also add id = id and ....Reason being is that it might delete all records excpet one

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by add id = id? Btw, I tried the second code example from Gordon Linoff but an error occurs: Query must have at least one destination field. The solution I found tells me to clear the "Track name AutoCorrect info check box." Could that damage other querys or formulas? Don't want to damage the Data Base...